# Get separate First and Last Name in Outlook 365 Addin using C#

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

currently I am using *mailItem.To* property to get name of person from whom I am receiving mail. It contains full name of that individual. I want to *get both first and last name separately*. Is this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`To/CC/BCC` properties contains a ";" separated list of display names.

Loop through the `MailItem.Recipients` collection instead and access `Recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().FirstName` / `LastName` properties (handle exceptions and nulls appropriately).

Comment: Hi @Dmitry, I printed number of recipents by mailItem.Recipients.Count. Then I iterated through mailItem.Recipients.Count in for loop(not foreach because foreach loop was not providing any identifiers) with iterator i. But mailItem.Recipients[i].AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().FirstName is throwing errors(inside for) ArrayIndexOutOfBound and NullReferneceException for index 0 and 1 resp. I checked the index of reciepent by mailItem.Recipients.Remove(0) which is throwing ArrayIndexOutOfBound error and mailItem.Recipients.Remove(1) is working. I also used OutlookSpy, but haven't got any solution.

Comment: All collections in Outlook Object Model are 1 based, not 0.The loop must be from 1 to Recipients.Count inclusively.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out by OutlookSpy. But still facing issue in getting last name only, so using splitting full name method. Thanks for the help @Dmitry.

Comment: What is the issue? As long as the recipient comes from your local Exchange domain, you should be able to read the LastName property.

Comment: When I call MailItem.Recipients[i].AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser() for a Outlook domain account, it returns IDispatch and I can easily get LastName(Refer here : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yMeJOAGp1QbCkYX8qLn-XDbN2XFaWQ0y/view?usp=sharing ). But if I do the same for accounts having other than Outlook Domain, the method returns null and I cannot get LastName(refer here : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mQs74aIRDg9DiRn0l3mSYu279hiiUDiN/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Yes, that is how it is supposed to work - your need to have 3 branches - (1) GetExchangeUser (2) GetContact and (3)  - if two previous attempts returned null, just Recipient.Name.

Comment: Yes, the first two methods are returning null for non outlook domain, so I am using Recipient.Name.split().